# Class object array can get only one object

Tags: java, arrays

So recently I've got into this problem, that every time I try to add two+ cars(trucks, busses or vehicles) program gets null pointer reference. Seems like my array can only hold one object. Why is that? Array size is set to 200... Adding one object works like a charm. This also works on C#. But not in Java.

```
public class Town {

    public int MaxNumberOfCars = 200;
    public String Dealership;
    public String Adress;
    public String Phone;
    public Car[] Cars = new Car[MaxNumberOfCars];
    public Bus[] Busses = new Bus[MaxNumberOfCars];
    public Truck [] Trucks = new Truck[MaxNumberOfCars];
    public Vehicles[] Vehicles = new Vehicles[MaxNumberOfCars];
    public static int carCount;
    public static int busCount;
    public static int truckCount;
    public static int vehicleCount;
    public int townVehicleCount;
    public int DealershipCount;
    public double avgage;


    public Town(String dealership, String adress, String phone) {
        Dealership = dealership;
        Adress = adress;
        Phone = phone;
    }

    public void AddCar(Car car) {
        Cars[carCount++] = car;
        vehicleCount++;
    }
```

The code where I'm accesing the AddCar:

```
private static void Read(String text, Town[] towns) {
    String text1 = text;
    String dealership = null, adress = null, phone = null;

    ArrayList<String> line = new ArrayList<>();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text1, "\n");
    int count = st.countTokens()-3;
    if (line != null) {
        dealership = st.nextToken();
        adress = st.nextToken();
        phone = st.nextToken();

        towns[townCount] = new Town(dealership, adress, phone);

        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            String string = st.nextToken();
            String[] values = string.split(";");
            String licenseplates = values[0]; // 004
            char type = values[1].charAt(0);
            String brand = values[2];
            String model = values[3];
            YearMonth yearofmake = YearMonth.parse(values[4]);
            YearMonth techinspection = YearMonth.parse(values[5]);
            String fuel = values[6];
            int fuelconsumption = Integer.valueOf(values[7]);
            switch (type) {
                case 'c':
                    Car car = new Car(licenseplates, brand, model, yearofmake, techinspection, fuel, fuelconsumption);
                    towns[townCount].AddCar(car);
                    towns[townCount].AddVehicle(car);
                    break;
            }
            townCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code where you are using `Town` object.

Comment: @gurwinderSingh done.

Comment: I agree with @GurwinderSingh. I just ran the code on my machine with a test `main()` and it compiled and ran. I suspect that your client code is broken. Please add in the method that is throwing the error. Also, if need be, try to whittle it down as much as possible so that you have a MVCE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LukasBaranauskas would you please post the stack trace you are getting?

Comment: @entpnerd It says NullPointerException when I'm adding a second car int the same town (line :  towns[townCount].AddCar(car);)

Comment: Thanks. Answer added below on what I think the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are incrementing `townCount` without there being enough towns in your array `towns`. You need to either add more towns to your array, or delete the `townCount++;` line at the end of your for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why your count variables are static?
I think first you must change this. then you must add some validation like checking MaxNumberOfCars validation in your addCar method.

Comment: if MaxNumberOfCars  exceed then you will receive ArrayIndexOfBoundException

Comment: Made count variables static. Nothing changed.